# Iterating through list in python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

How will I do the following?

```
class a:
    def get(self):
        return (1, 2)

i = a() #this is variable that i wont have access directly and should be accessed only from list P below
P = [i, i, i, i]
Q = [P, P, P, P]
```

I want is

```
L = [list of all i.get() results iterating through Q and P]
```

for eg

```
L = [px.get() for px in P for P in Q] # I want something like this
```

i.e

```
L = [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: Presumably the fact that `P` contains 4 times `a` has nothing to do with the *class* `a` here?

Comment: I am in situation where i need to access the methods of the same class but numerous of different objects. I just wanted to make my question simple here

Comment: So you want `[P[0].get(), P[1].get(), ..., Q[2].get(), Q[3].get()]` instead? Because your sample code suggests otherwise.

Comment: sorry,please see my edited post

Comment: So `Q` contains `[[i, i, i, i], [i, i, i, i], [i, i, i, i], [i, i, i, i]]`? Then you'd expect *16* `(1, 2)` tuples, not 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
L = [i.get() for P in Q for i in P]
```

This gives you `[Q[0][0].get(), Q[0][1].get(), ..., Q[-1][-2].get(), Q[-1][-1].get()]`

The double loop is just like a nested for loop outside of a list comprehension, the above is the equivalent of:

```
L = []
for P in Q:
    for i in P:
        L.append(i.get())
```

The list comprehension follows the same order of loops, nesting is translated to loops being listed from left to right.

Comment: Please just iterate and use .get() method for elements of list P only without using i variable. I am using i just to show my situation. I need to iterate through Q and P to get all 'a' object and call its method..

Answer (score 0):

Replicating a list can be done with the `*` operator in Python (i.e. [multiplying a list](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)):

```
>>> [i.get()] * (len(P) + len(Q))
[(1,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2)]
```